# How can i print DataGridView in C# ?

Tags: c#, datagridview, printing

I have a datagridview to show my entries and i want a print out just like an excel sheet.

Is there any way I can print datagridview entirely or what kind of control would you suggest to store my data in and print it?

Or how do I use HTML tables in C# to help me create and print them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/PrintDataGridView.aspx)'s a solution.

Comment: I know that you have pointed to an article illustrating the exact solution to the question. But, is it possible you could elaborate further and give a proper answer?

Answer (score 1):

Theres a lot of solution online. you can google it
[here](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/grid/printdatagridview.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You have to know about the class **PrintDocument** in .NET Framework library, This class helps you print any Rectangles
And your mission is to convert the table in datagridview into rectangles (or draw new rectangles which match the table in datagridview in size including drawing strings (these strings are the contents of cells)?). After that, you can use the methods and more in the class **PrintDocument** to start printing.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/printingdatagridview.aspx

You have to join the codeproject network first to be able to download the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // make a function named zpt 

 int rw=dataGridView1.Rows.Count;     //define rw as globly variable in form
 public void zpt()
    {
         PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
         PrintDocument pdoc = new PrintDocument();
        PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
        Font font = new Font("Arial", 10);
        PaperSize psz = new PaperSize("Custom", 100, 200);
        pd.Document = pdoc;
        pd.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psz;
        pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height = 820;
        pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width = 700;
        pdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);
        DialogResult res = pd.ShowDialog();
        if (res == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            PrintPreviewDialog prv = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            prv.Document = pdoc;
            res = prv.ShowDialog();
            if (res == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pdoc.Print();
            }
        }

    }
    void pdoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
        Font font = new Font("Courier New", 10);
        float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();
        int startX = 50;
        int startY = 65;
        int Offset = 40;
        graphics.DrawString("Welcome to Bakery Shop", new Font("Courier New", 10), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
        Offset = Offset + 20;
        string underLine = "------------------------------------------";
        graphics.DrawString(underLine, new Font("Courier New", 10), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
        Offset = Offset + 20;
        int a = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value), new Font("Courier New", 10), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
            graphics.DrawString("\t"+Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value), new Font("Courier New", 10), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
            Offset = Offset + 20;
        }
    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[rw].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[rw].Cells[1].Value = textBox2.Text;
        rw++;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // on print Button which is in your window for code this...
        zpt();
    }
```